# block outgoing internet calls from inside a container

Tags: server, firewall, lxc, container

This question is not similar to my [earlier post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258135/blocking-all-outgoing-ports-and-its-consequences). This is pretty simple I think, I just don't know enough about networking and the ubuntu firewall.

I followed [this article](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2011/10/virtualization-ec2-cloud-using-lxc) and setup a linux container inside my ubuntu server on ec2. I can access the internet from my container.

```
                       | ----Ubuntu Server on EC2 -----
 ==== INTERNET <==== > |  some magic routes traffic  <===   lxc container
                       |                                    [192.168.3.1] 
                       |------------------------------
```

I needed the internet inside the container only to **install dependencies** for my app. Now I need to shut off internet access. I wouldn't mind any other approach like prevent a certain user account from the internet.

This is how the network config goes, Any ideas, clues or suggestions on what I should read will be appreciated :

---

There is a network bridge :

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl setfd br0 0
ifconfig br0 192.168.3.1 up
```

Then I did this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then this : `cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
interface = br0
listen-address = 127.0.0.1
listen-address = 192.168.3.1
expand-hosts
domain = containers
dhcp-range = 192.168.3.50,192.168.3.200,1h
```

Then : `cat etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
prepend domain-search "containers.";
```

Then I ran :

> dhclient -e IF_METRIC=100 -pf /var/run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out myself.

I just do :

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
```

And voila! :) Of course, if I do `ping www.google.com` it resolves the IP for google then fails. So dns still works.

An easy *toggle* solution for this would be appreciated with votes :)